# Of something? clarification

Tags: grammar

I came across the following sentence ( from "Applied Nonlinear Control book by SLOTINE"

"An important concept in phase plane analysis is that of a singular point."

It seems to me that saying "... is the singular point " is clearer that saying "... is that of a singular point". Am I correct? and what does "that of" in this context mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[That](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/that#Pronoun)* is a pronoun, standing for *an important concept*.  The sentence says (or was intended to say) that  singular points are an important concept in phase plane analysis:  “An important concept in phase plane analysis is the  concept of singular points.”

No particular singular point is being singled out here (a function may have many singular points), so a definite article (as in *the singular point*) is not appropriate.  Indefinite article *a* is acceptable, but using a plural form,  *singular points*, is better.